# How can I transform a Point2f with a matrix on Android?

Tags: android, matrix, transformation

I'm developing for Android and I'm using the `android.renderscript.Matrix3f` class to do some calculations.

What I need to do now is to now is to do something like `mat.tranform(pointIn, pointOut);`

So I need to transform a matrix by a given `Point` class. In `awt` I would simply do this:

```
AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform();
Point2D.Float p = new Point2D.Float();
t.transform( p, p );
```

But in Android I now have this:

```
Matrix3f t = new Matrix3f();
PointF p = new PointF();
// Now I need to tranform it somehow..
```

But the `Matrix3f` class in Android doesn't have a `Matrix.transform(Point2D ptSrc, Point2D ptDst)` method.

So I guess I have to do the transformation manually. But I'm not really sure how that works. From what I've seen it's something like a `translate` and then a `rotate`?

Could anyone please tell me how to do this in code?

Answer (score 1):

Matrix transform functions are just implementing [matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), which is pretty straightforward. For the simple (non-homogeneous) 2D case, you have a matrix of four values:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

multiplied by a 2-vector (x, y).

I'm most used to the convention that vectors are columns, and so are multiplied on the right, like so: 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
ax + by \\
cx + dy
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Here, each entry of the result vector is the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of the input vector with the corresponding row of the matrix.
(The opposite convention is also valid, where vectors are columns and are multiplied on the left - just know which one your libraries expect)

If you want homogeneous coordinates (necessary for translating with a matrix), then you're "really" working with a 3-vector, (x, y, 1), something like:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & h\\
c & d & v
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
ax + by + h \\
cx + dy + v
\end{bmatrix}
$$

or equivalently:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & h\\
c & d & v\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
ax + by + h \\
cx + dy + v\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So you might be able to use the 3-vector support that already exists in your library, or implement it yourself using the formula above.